# two Array equal to each other by the index "Java "

Tags: java, arrays

If the user Sully typed his name after running this program, the program should output

> Hello Sully you are Manager !

but what's happening is, the program will print that Sully is the manager and will keep comparing Sully with the others values in the array. Im just learning Arrays in java.

```
    public class Aconstructors {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
            String user ;
            String [] empName , empPos ;
            empName = new String [2] ;
            empName [0] = "Sully" ;
            empName [1] = "John" ;
            empPos = new String [2] ;
            empPos [0] = "Manager" ;
            empPos [1] = "Employ" ;

            System.out.println("Enter Your Name to know Your Position : ");
            user = scan.nextLine()  ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i <empName.length;i++ ) {
                //check if user input is equals
                if (empName[i].equals(user)) {
                    // indexes are equals
                    empName.equals(empPos.length );
                    System.out.printf("Hello %s you are %s !!\n",empName[i],empPos[i]);
                    // if user input is not equal
                }
                else if   (!empName[i].equals(user))  {
                    System.out.println("unknowing user !! ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

output for John :

```
Enter Your Name to know Your Position : 
John
unknowing user !! << as you see here java checking the values 
Hello John you are the Employ  !! << java found John
```

output for Sully :

```
Enter Your Name to know Your Position : 
Sully
Hello Sully you are Manager !! << found Sully 
unknowing user !! << didnt stop
```

Comment: Wow. Did you hear about punctuation at all? Your text is completely unreadable. This is not WhatsApp.

Comment: You should properly format your code; it'll make it easier to read. You should also use proper interpunction when asking questions, as your question is hard to understand in its current form.

Comment: From what it looks like you should consider using a Map instead of an array. In Map you can store a (key, value) pair which in your case can be the name and the index or vice versa. Not sure why you are using arrays.

Comment: Take a deep breath. Breathe. Now state your question again by using sentences...

Comment: and.... breathe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a boolean variable `unknown=true;` before the loop to check if the name exists in the list. If the name is found in the list change `unknown=false;`. 
When the loop finishes then you print the message "unknown" if the variable hasn't changed meaning the name is not in the list.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
String user ;
String [] empName , empPos ;
empName = new String [2] ;
empName [0] = "Sully" ;
empName [1] = "John" ;
empPos = new String [2] ;
empPos [0] = "Manager" ;
empPos [1] = "Employ" ;

System.out.println("Enter Your Name to know Your Position : ");
user = scan.nextLine()  ;

boolean unknown = true;

for (int i = 0 ; i <empName.length;i++ ) {
    //check if user input is equals
    if (empName[i].equals(user)) {
        unknown = false;
        System.out.printf("Hello %s you are %s !!\n",empName[i], empPos[i]);
        break;
    }
}

if (unknown)
    System.out.println("unknowing user !! ");
```

Comment: thank you for your help it did helps with the first index but when i type John it gives me Unknowing user then gives me John positions

Comment: @setget you mixed the answers. This one does not give you  Unknowing user

Comment: it does give me Unknowing user !! i didnt mix any answers .

Comment: @setget copy and paste this answer and if it gives you Unknowing user I will resign from this site. The other answer gives you Unknowing user  if you type John

Comment: @setget What do you mean? probably you thought that the working code was the other question.

Answer (score 0):

try to improve your for loop like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <empName.length;i++ ) {
            //check if user input is equals
            if (empName[i].equals(user)) {
                // indexes are equals 
                System.out.printf("Hello "+empName[i]+" you are "+empPos[i]);
                break;
                // if user input is not equal
            } else if   (!empName[i].equals(user))  {
                System.out.println("unknowing user !! ");
            }
        }
```

you just need to compare your user input with you empName array and print the position of that employee is pretty simple because your indexes are same for both and use break to breaking the loop if you have found the match.

Comment: Thank you for your help . the break helped with the first index but when i type John it keep giving me unknowing user !! then give me John positions . do i need pointer ? to fix this problem ?

Comment: @setget did you try this answer?